# Graph output after plot button use

Tags: r, shiny

I read online about using the action button if you want to have control some portion of the code. But where do i put the observeEvent() function so that it plots the graph after pushing the plot button

```
 library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(quantmod)

# Define UI for application that draws a bar graph
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("My Plot"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("text", "Enter company name:", width = NULL,
                placeholder = "comp.name"),
      dateRangeInput("dates", h3(strong("Date Range")), 
                     start = "2001-01-01", end = Sys.Date(),
                     min = "0000-01-01", max = Sys.Date(),
                     format = "dd-mm-yy", separator = strong("to"),
                     autoclose = TRUE),
      submitButton(text = "submit"),
      actionButton("button", "PLOT")),

    # Show a plot
    mainPanel( h1(strong(textOutput("Company"))),
               DT::dataTableOutput("MRF"),
               plotOutput("finally")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$MRF <- DT::renderDataTable({
    tyu2 <- getSymbols(input$text , src = "yahoo", verbose = TRUE,
                       to = max(input$dates), from = min(input$dates) ,
                       auto.assign = FALSE)})
  output$finally <- renderPlot({
    tyu2 <- getSymbols(input$text , src = "yahoo", verbose = TRUE,
                       to = max(input$dates), from = min(input$dates) ,
                       auto.assign = FALSE, row.names = TRUE)
    ggplot(data = tyu2 , aes(x= min(input$dates):max(input$dates) ,
                             y= tyu2[2]))+
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "blue")+
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
      xlab("Dates")+ ylab(input$text)
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Till now, it is giving this error from the beginning itself. I want it to wait till submit button and plot button have been pressed

```
Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (6378): x, y
```

Comment: There are two mistakes here. 1)  Aesthetics does not match. 2) Action button code not entered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(quantmod)

# Define UI for application that draws a bar graph
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("My Plot"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("text", "Enter company name:", width = NULL,placeholder = "comp.name"),
      dateRangeInput("dates", h3(strong("Date Range")), start = "2001-01-01", end = Sys.Date(),min = "0000-01-01", max = Sys.Date(), format = "dd-mm-yy", separator = strong("to")),
      actionButton("submit", "submit"),
      actionButton("plot", "PLOT")),

    # Show a plot
    mainPanel(h1(strong(textOutput("Company"))),
               DT::dataTableOutput("MRF"),
               plotOutput("finally")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

  mydata <- eventReactive(input$submit,{
    req(input$text)
    getSymbols(input$text , src = "yahoo", verbose = TRUE,
               to = max(input$dates), from = min(input$dates) ,
               auto.assign = FALSE)
  })

  output$MRF <- DT::renderDataTable({mydata()})

  myplotdata <- eventReactive(input$plot,{
    autoplot(mydata()[,2])+
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "blue")+
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
      xlab("Dates")+ ylab(input$text)
  })

  output$finally <- renderPlot({
    myplotdata()
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]